# Which is greater: $n^{1.01} $ or $n\cdot log_{10}(n)$ ?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Can someone please explain how the right side can be less than the left side? I have plugged numerous numbers into n and every time I get the left side being less than the right side. My professor is convinced the right side is less than the left side. He has a PHD in math so he should be right. I just don't understand his explanation.

$n^{1.01} < n\cdot log_{10}(n)$

$1000^{1.01} < 1000*log_{10}(1000)$

$1071.51 < 3000$

Comment: The question amounts to asking which is larger, $\sqrt[100]{n}$ or $\log(n)$. For sufficiently large $n$, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

In the race between a (positive) power and a logarithm, the power wins eventually.
So $n^{0.01} > \lg(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$, and thus $n^{1.01} > n \lg(n)$ for those same $n$.  But how large is 
"sufficiently large"?  In this case, $n > 3.8125 \times 10^{237}$ approximately.

Comment: Sir, is there any calculus trick to show that?

Comment: @Sush  Yes.  The usual method is to use L'Hospital's rule.  You can use it to show that $\ln^a(x)/x^b$ converges to $0$ as $x$ diverges to $\infty$ for any $a,b>0$.  So any power of $x$, no matter how small, eventually grows (much) larger (and faster) than any power of $\ln$, no matter how large.  As Robert's posts indicates, "eventually" can be a very long time.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, Thanks a lot. I think it should be $\log_a(x)/x^b$, right?

Comment: How were you able to calculate $ 3.8125 \times 10^{237}$ as being "sufficiently large" enough? That number is so big I would have no idea where to start.

Comment: I think we pupils should use [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+n+for+n%5E0.01%3Dlog+n). Note that we get two solutions for $n$, but at $n=2.746\dots$ , graph of $log (n)$ crosses graph of $n^{0.01}$ from beneath and thus after $n=3.8125 \times 10^{237}$ only, we get that $n^{1.01} > n \log(n)$. Note also that, for interval $0\leq n< 2.746\dots$,too, inequality $n^{1.01} > n \log(n)$ holds.

Comment: @Sush No, but you can change the base of the logarithm as well and everything stays true.  I meant the $a$ as a power.  So, for example, $\ln^2(x)=(\ln(x))^2$.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, Thanks a lot. I thought that way too! beautiful and amazing mathematics.